# Most common enemies in Pathfinder: Kingmaker (Standard Game, No DLC)?

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

Which are the most common enemies in Pathfinder: Kingmaker? This would be an interesting info eg. for the Ranger's Favored Enemies, but could be useful for other classes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humans are a good safe bet for a favored enemy early game.  Undead are also okay.  As for favored terrain, select underground early game, and first world (fey realm) later on.  As you may have guessed, fey are also an important choice as a favored enemy type.